# How do I divide a deep network into two separate network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I learned a network with two inputs.it works as an autoencoder. In the first part of the network, the inputs are fed to network and after some processing and passing from gaussian noise layer the second part of network is used. During learning all the network learnd together, but for test I need to spilit it to two part. First part gets two inputs and the second network gets an input that was the output of first network. So when I want to make two models for each part, it said the second part does not have an input. Could you please tell me what shoud I do? Is it possible to make a same nework for second part but learn with first network's weights? I will put the code very soon. I am working in keras. Thank you

my code is :

```
wt_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(49999,4,4))
w_expand=wt_random.astype(np.float32)
wv_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(9999,4,4))
wv_expand=wv_random.astype(np.float32)
x,y,z=w_expand.shape
w_expand=w_expand.reshape((x,y,z,1))
x,y,z=wv_expand.shape
wv_expand=wv_expand.reshape((x,y,z,1))

#-----------------building w test---------------------------------------------
w_test = np.random.randint(2,size=(1,4,4))
w_test=w_test.astype(np.float32)
w_test=w_test.reshape((1,4,4,1))


#-----------------------encoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wtm=Input((4,4,1))
image = Input((28, 28, 1))
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1e')(image)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2e')(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e')(conv2)
BN=BatchNormalization()(conv3)
encoded =  Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='encoded_I')(BN)


wpad=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda xy: xy[0] + Kr.backend.spatial_2d_padding(xy[1], padding=((0, 24), (0, 24))))
encoded_merged=wpad([encoded,wtm])


deconv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu', padding='same', name='convl1d')(encoded_merged)
deconv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu', padding='same', name='convl2d')(deconv1)
deconv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu',padding='same', name='convl3d')(deconv2)
deconv4 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu',padding='same', name='convl4d')(deconv3)
BNd=BatchNormalization()(deconv4)

decoded = Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='decoder_output')(BNd) 

model=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=decoded)

decoded_noise = GaussianNoise(0.5)(decoded)

convw1 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='conl1w')(decoded_noise)#24
convw2 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='convl2w')(convw1)#20
convw3 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu' ,name='conl3w')(convw2)#16
convw4 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu' ,name='conl4w')(convw3)#12
convw5 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='conl5w')(convw4)#8
convw6 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='conl6w')(convw5)#4
convw7 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='conl7w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw6)#4
convw8 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='conl8w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw7)#4
convw9 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='conl9w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw8)#4
convw10 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='conl10w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw9)#4
BNed=BatchNormalization()(convw10)
pred_w = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='reconstructed_W',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BNed)  
model2=Model(inputs=decoded_noise,outputs=pred_w)
w_extraction=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=[decoded,pred_w])

w_extraction.summary()
```

the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 55, in 
>       model2=Model(inputs=decoded_noise,outputs=pred_w)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py",
>   line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 93, in **init**
>       self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 231, in _init_graph_network
>       self.inputs, self.outputs)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1443, in _map_graph_network
>       str(layers_with_complete_input))
>
> ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor
>   Tensor("input_14:0", shape=(?, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32) at layer
>   "input_14". The following previous layers were accessed without issue:
>   []

**the new code**

```
wtm=Input((4,4,1))
image = Input((28, 28, 1))

#your code:
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1e')(image)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2e')(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e')(conv2)
BN=BatchNormalization()(conv3)
encoded =  Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='encoded_I')(BN)


wpad=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda xy: xy[0] + Kr.backend.spatial_2d_padding(xy[1], padding=((0, 24), (0, 24))))
encoded_merged=wpad([encoded,wtm])
#end of your code

encoder = Model([image, wtm], encoded_merged)

encoded_input = Input((28,28,1))

#your code
deconv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu', padding='same', name='convl1d')(encoded_input)
deconv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu', padding='same', name='convl2d')(deconv1)
deconv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu',padding='same', name='convl3d')(deconv2)
deconv4 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu',padding='same', name='convl4d')(deconv3)
BNd=BatchNormalization()(deconv4)

decoded = Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='decoder_output')(BNd) 

#end of your code

decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoded)

decoded_input = Input((28,28,1))

#your code
decoded_noise = GaussianNoise(0.5)(decoded_input)

convw1 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='conl1w')(decoded_noise)#24
convw2 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='convl2w')(convw1)#20
convw3 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu' ,name='conl3w')(convw2)#16
convw4 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu' ,name='conl4w')(convw3)#12
convw5 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='conl5w')(convw4)#8
convw6 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='conl6w')(convw5)#4
convw7 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='conl7w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw6)#4
convw8 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='conl8w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw7)#4
convw9 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='conl9w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw8)#4
convw10 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='conl10w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw9)#4
BNed=BatchNormalization()(convw10)
pred_w = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='reconstructed_W',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BNed)  

#end of your code
noiseNet = Model(inputs=decoded_input,outputs=pred_w)

#input for full nets
full_wtm = Input((4,4,1))
full_image = Input((28, 28, 1)) 

#encoded 
full_encoded = encoder([full_image, full_wtm])

#decoded
full_decoded = decoder(full_encoded)

#with noise
full_w = noiseNet(full_decoded)

#autoencoder
autoencoder = Model([full_image,full_wtm], full_decoded)

#full net
w_extraction = Model([full_image, full_wtm], [full_decoded, full_w])

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
x_validation=x_train[1:10000,:,:]
x_train=x_train[10001:60000,:,:]
#
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_validation = x_validation.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_validation = np.reshape(x_validation, (len(x_validation), 28, 28, 1))

#---------------------compile and train the model------------------------------
#opt=SGD(momentum=0.99)
w_extraction.compile(optimizer='adam', loss={'decoder_output':'mse','reconstructed_W':'binary_crossentropy'}, loss_weights={'decoder_output': 0.45, 'reconstructed_W': 1.0},metrics=['mae'])
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=20)
#rlrp = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=20, min_delta=1E-4, verbose=1)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model_5x5F_dil_Los751.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
history=w_extraction.fit([x_train,w_expand], [x_train,w_expand],
          epochs=200,
          batch_size=16, 
          validation_data=([x_validation,wv_expand], [x_validation,wv_expand]),
          callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='E:/concatnatenetwork', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False),es,mc])
w_extraction.summary()
```

**the produced error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 136, in 
>       w_extraction.compile(optimizer='adam', loss={'decoder_output':'mse','reconstructed_W':'binary_crossentropy'},
>   loss_weights={'decoder_output': 0.45, 'reconstructed_W':
>   1.0},metrics=['mae'])
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 119, in compile
>       str(self.output_names))
>
> ValueError: Unknown entry in loss dictionary: "decoder_output". Only
>   expected the following keys: ['model_17', 'model_18']

Comment: Provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should have created the models separate in the first place.

```
net1 = createNet1()
net2 = createNet2()

net2OutFrom1 = net2(net1.output)

entireModel = Model(net1.input, net2OutFrom1)
```

Then you train `entireModel` and you can automatically use `net1` and `net2` without any trouble.

### Doing it when your net was made as a single net.

You need to create a new input:

```
net2Input = Input(input_shape)
```

Then pass it through all layers of the second net.

```
out = originalNet.layers[firstLayerOfNet2](net2Input)
out = originalNet.layers[secondLayerOfNet2](out)
out = originalNet.layers[thirdLayerOfNet2](out)
....
```

Then create the second net separately:

```
net2 = Model(net2Input, out)
```

The first net can still be easily created:

```
net1 = Model(originalNet.input, originalNet.layers[lastLayerOfNet1].output)
```

### With your example

#### Individual nets

Encoder

```
wtm=Input((4,4,1))
image = Input((28, 28, 1))

#your code:
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1e')(image)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2e')(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e')(conv2)
BN=BatchNormalization()(conv3)
encoded =  Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='encoded_I')(BN)


wpad=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda xy: xy[0] + Kr.backend.spatial_2d_padding(xy[1], padding=((0, 24), (0, 24))))
encoded_merged=wpad([encoded,wtm])
#end of your code

encoder = Model([image, wtm], encoded_merged)
```

Decoder

```
encoded_input = Input(shape_of_encoded_merged_without_batch_size)

#your code
deconv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu', padding='same', name='convl1d')(encoded_input)
deconv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu', padding='same', name='convl2d')(deconv1)
deconv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu',padding='same', name='convl3d')(deconv2)
deconv4 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu',padding='same', name='convl4d')(deconv3)
BNd=BatchNormalization()(deconv4)

decoded = Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='decoder_output')(BNd) 

#end of your code

decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoded)
```

Noise net

```
decoded_input = Input(shape_of_decoded_without_batch_size)

#your code
decoded_noise = GaussianNoise(0.5)(decoded_input)

convw1 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='conl1w')(decoded_noise)#24
convw2 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='convl2w')(convw1)#20
convw3 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu' ,name='conl3w')(convw2)#16
convw4 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu' ,name='conl4w')(convw3)#12
convw5 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='conl5w')(convw4)#8
convw6 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='conl6w')(convw5)#4
convw7 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='conl7w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw6)#4
convw8 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='conl8w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw7)#4
convw9 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='conl9w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw8)#4
convw10 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='conl10w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw9)#4
BNed=BatchNormalization()(convw10)
pred_w = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='reconstructed_W',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BNed)  

#end of your code
noiseNet = Model(inputs=noiseInput,outputs=pred_w)
```

#### Joining nets

```
#input for full nets
full_wtm = Input((4,4,1))
full_image = Input((28, 28, 1)) 

#encoded 
full_encoded = encoder([full_image, full_wtm])

#decoded
full_decoded = decoder(full_encoded)

#with noise
full_w = noiseNet(full_decoded)

#autoencoder
autoencoder = Model([full_image,full_wtm], full_decoded)

#full net
w_extraction = Model([full_image, full_wtm], [full_decoded, full_w])
```

---

You need to train again with this solution. Any net you train will train all the others.

Comment: I put my code above. I have one model named model for the first part of my network and other model named w_extraction for all the network but for the second part of network I need a model that the input of it is decoded noise and the output is pred_w. I learned the network, but now I need to have the model of second part. what should I do now?do I learn the network again? because decoded noise is the output of Gaussian noise layer and it should send as input to second part of the network

Comment: what is creatNet1() and creatNet2() I should define these networks as functions? because I am a beginner and I do not know some of these that you said.

Comment: my problem is I have to send the output of Gaussian noise layer to the second network and I do not know how can I do it? could you please tell me what should I do?

Comment: I put the model and the error that is created please help me with this problem.

Comment: could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: @david, see answer.

Comment: I changed my code based on your suggestion, but it produces this error that I do not know why this happens. I put the code and error above. could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: It`s because your model doesn`t have "decoder_output" since you merged a lot of models together. The full model has "model_1" and "model_2". Just add the losses without model/layer names: `w_extraction.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=['mse','binary_crossentropy'], loss_weights=[0.45, 1.0],metrics=['mae'])`.

Comment: If I change the loss function based on your suggestion, it will consider the loss for the models that I want?thank you

Comment: Use the losses in the same order that you defined in `Model(..., outputs=[output1,output2])`.

Comment: Or give a name to your submodels: `decoder=Model(...., name='decoder_model')` and `noiseNet = Model(..., name='noise_net')`. Then use these names in the loss. (These are the two outpu models that compose the full model)